# How can you programmatically tell when a Kerberos credential will expire?

Tags: kerberos, credentials

When a user does a kinit, the /tmp/krb5cc_* credential cache is created.  On Linux, how can I tell when it will expire?  (I am programming in either C or C++.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Kerberos V5 API Documentation http://cryptnet.net/mirrors/docs/krb5api.html
You can also look at klist.c which is the command line tool implementation to list the credentials.

Comment: RVM - the klist comment was just perfect.  After looking at that code, I have just what I need.  Many thanks.